# End equals in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to fix it:

My code:

```
this.score = 6;
this.lastScore = this.score;
this.score = 0;
```

But when I render it `{{ lastScore }}`, it changes to zero when it is not zero. How can I stop it? I'm looking for a online guide, but I can't found it

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are mutating the object and sharing the reference.

```
this.score = 6;
this.lastScore = Object.assign(this.score);
this.score = 0;
```